# Removing Time From Date from a SQL server in a asp.net Repeater

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am creating a repeater in aspx to just simple display a table from a SQL Server.

The dates are coming back with the time added, which I think is a normal thing with SQL. But how to cut the value down to size within aspx? Can I change the string within the text property or do I need to do it else where? Sorry I am an aspx noob.

```
Date    
---------------------
8/14/2013 12:00:00 AM
8/13/2013 12:00:00 AM
8/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
8/10/2013 12:00:00 AM
8/9/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Code:

```
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="TestRepeater">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <Table>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th><asp:Label runat="server" ID="L1" Text='<%# Eval("Date")%>' ></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:Label runat="server" ID="L2" Text='<%# Eval("Customer")%>' ></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:Label runat="server" ID="L3" Text='<%# Eval("Location")%>' ></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:button runat="server" ID="button1" Text="See Ticket" BorderStyle="Groove" BackColor="Silver" /></th>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
            </Table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why choose a Repeater for this over a GridView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the format parameter to databind:

```
<%# Eval("Date", "{0:d}")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your SQL SELECT statement, you can convert the date to a text string using the `CONVERT` function.

Here are a list of formats you can use.
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: In my humble opinion, layout work should be left to the front-end system whenever possible.